# Adobe DTM Capture Form Data using Data Element

Tags: adobe-analytics

I want to use event base rule to capture form submission data in Adobe Analytics and Universal  Analytics. I tried using Data Element custom script to get the form data. However, I cannot find a way to pass the form object to the Data Element custom script.

That are more than one form on the page. I need to get the data from the correct form.

Does any one has a solution or work around?

Answer (score 2):

If you setup an event based rule, you can choose Form > Submit as the event type, and specify the element type of your form submit button (e.g. input or button).

Then you can use a Data > Custom textbox (or in your custom code section) use `this` to reference the button that was clicked as a starting point, but from there, DTM doesn't really have a native way to reference form elements, so you will need to write your own js code for that.  If you have a framework like jQuery already implemented on your site, it's easier to get the data with that, using something like `$(this).closest('form')`

Comment: So I was going to do something similar to this (I'm saving one of the user inputted values as an event) but was unsure how to attach the return value from the custom code to the event. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @michaelp not quite sure what your scenario is but it sounds like you are wanting to do e.g. `events=123`.  DTM does not currently support popping numeric or currency events with a custom value, nor does it currently support popping an ecommerce event in products var (it doesn't even support popping products var itself).  So, you will need to set those AA vars yourself in AA's custom code section in the rule. I suggest you set a data element in the condition and then reference the data element in the custom code section so it is exposed to any other tools you may have in the rule

Comment: That's actually the exact route that I went. I just thought that DTM would have some better way of implementing it. Thanks for the confirmation.